# Can I add custom titles to ajax powered website with hashbang (#!) URLs?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, seo, hashbang

I'm using ajax powered WordPress theme which has hashbang URLs like www.example.com/#!/page. I'm wondering can I add custom titles and descriptions for each page because of SEO? The site isn't indexed yet so I cannot see how Google sees pages with hashbang URLs but I assume it will have the same title as the home page? Btw the website is www.jsomedia.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't quite understand how Google supports the #!. Here is the specification:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

The google crawler does not crawl the #!ed URL but an alternate one using _escaped_fragment_. This alternate URL should be a plain html version of the content the #! value represents.

As it is plain html it can contain a title tag and meta description.